# Puppet file without name

Tags: puppet

I am currently reviewing a module from the puppet forge and I wonder what does these line do :

```
File {
  owner => $owner,
  group => $group,
  mode  => '0644',
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That construct declares [resource defaults](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_defaults.html) for declarations in its scope.  `File` resources declared within the *dynamic* scope of that declaration will have the specified `owner` and / or `group` and / or `mode` properties where they do not declare their own values for those properties.